# Getting an Error - "cannot be used in conjunction (ArgumentError)" Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am working on a Ruby course and I came across an error when running one of the examples.  Here is my Ruby class:

```
require 'json'

class User

  attr_accessor :email, :name, :permissions

  def initialize(*args)
    @email = args[0]
    @name = args[1]
    @permissions = User.permisisons_from_template
  end

  def self.permisisons_from_template
    file = File.read 'user_permissions_template.json'
    JSON.load(file, nil, symbolize_names: true)
  end

  def save
    self_json = {email: @email, name: @name, permissions: @permissions}.to_json
    open('users.json', 'a') do |file|
      file.puts self_json
    end
  end

end
```

My runner file code looks like this:

```
require 'pp'
require_relative 'user'

user = User.new 'john.doe@example.com', 'John Doe'

pp user

user.save
```

I get this error when I run this command "ruby runner.rb":

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `initialize': options :symbolize_names and :create_additions cannot be  used in conjunction (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:335:in `load'
        from /home/ec2-user/environment/section2_project/user.rb:15:in `permisisons_from_template'
        from /home/ec2-user/environment/section2_project/user.rb:10:in `initialize'
        from runner.rb:4:in `new'
        from runner.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I looked for help on the site and the suggested fix was to remove the nil parameter.  Now, I am from a .Net background and I surmised that I could use `proc: nil` and that would work as well, which it did.  My assumption is that it didn't like the mixing of named parameters and positional parameters, but this isn't .Net, so I may just have gotten lucky with my guess.  The moderator for the site wasn't sure why the code failed and why removing nil fixed the issue.  So, my question is:

Why did the line `JSON.load(file, nil, symbolize_names: true)` fail, but `JSON.load(file, proc: nil, symbolize_names: true)` work?  Thanks.

Wade

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's happening here is that the arguments aren't being parsed in the way you're expecting. There's a feature in Ruby where any `key: value` at the end of the argument list are made into a `Hash` without the need to put the `{}` around them.

For example if you write a method:

```
def load(source, options = {})
end
```

This can be called as `load(source)` in which case `options` will be `{}`, or as something like `load(source, foo: 5, bar: true)` in which case `options` will be `{foo: 5, bar: true}`

The other detail is that optional parameters with default values are filled left to right.

Why is this relevant?

Well, in the case of `JSON.load(file, proc: nil, symbolize_names: true)` the `proc: nil, symbolize_names: true` becomes the Hash `{proc: nil, symbolize_names: true}` and this then fills the `proc` position in the argument list, leaving the `options` parameter with its default value. i.e. you aren't actually setting `symbolize_names: true` when you thought you were.

In the case of `JSON.load(file, nil, symbolize_names: true)`, the `nil` fills the value of the `proc` parameter, and `symbolize_names: true` becomes `options`. This gets combined with the default options in the JSON library to give the full set of options, `{:max_nesting=>false, :allow_nan=>true, :allow_blank=>true, :create_additions=>true, :symbolize_names=>true}` which then contains the conflict that the error message is referencing.

Comment: So true, that `JSON.load(file, nil, symbolize_names: false)` works.

Comment: Wow, I would not have that this is what was happening.  Though as I mentioned I am trained on .Net, so was making assumptions based on how it works.  Glad I asked, though is there somewhere I can look to get a bit more detail on this behavior?  Thanks @mikej

Comment: @iGian thanks for pointing that out as well.  Had to reread mikej's answer a few times to see why what you wrote was true.

Answer (score 2):

It is related on how arguments are passed in ruby methods.

[Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load) you can find the json module source for load method.

And here below there is my version ;) for a sort of explanation.

```
def load(source, proc = nil, options = {})
  # firs parameter required, second and third are optional
  puts "source: #{source}"
  puts "proc: #{proc}"
  puts "options: #{options}"
  puts "- "*20
end

my_dummy_proc = Proc.new{|e| e}

load('filename_1',my_dummy_proc , {option1: :option1, option2: :option2}) # the 3rd is a hash
load('filename_2', my_dummy_proc, option1: :option1, option2: :option2) # the 3rd as a hash but with no braces
load('filename_3') # you can pass just the first argument
load('filename_4', my_dummy_proc) # you can pass just the first and the second
load('filename_5', option1: :option1, option2: :option2) # but not just the first and the third, unless you set the 2nd to nil (a sort of placeholder) if you skip nil as 2nd parameter, the hash is assigned to the second argument
load('filename_6', nil, option1: :option1, option2: :option2) # if no 2nd argument is passed, you need to set the second parameter to nil (as a placeholder)
```

About the error message you got `:symbolize_names and :create_additions cannot be used in conjunction`,if you try, this should work:

`JSON.load(file, nil, symbolize_names: true, create_additions: false)`

Answer (score 1):

Change `symbolize_names: true` to `symbolize_names: false`.

Comment: If this does indeed address the issue, explaining why it does who would be good. In addition, does this approach work better than the accepted answer? An explanation as to why it does/doesn't would improve this answer also.

Comment: Ruby docs link is: [http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) symbolize_names: If set to true, returns symbols for the names (keys) in a JSON object. Otherwise (if set to false) strings are returned. Strings are the default.